# Pagination with an array of hashes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, redis

I have a simple array of hashes retrieved from Redis in my Ruby on Rails application. These are a list of items that I'd like to paginate in a view. They are not ActiveRecord based or based on any database ORM wrapper. They're simply retrieved like this:

```
@items = $redis.lrange("items-#{params[:id]}", 0, -1)
```

At this point I want to do something as simple as list 10 items per page and allow the user to paginate through them.

Is there a plugin/tool available that works on straight arrays? It seems most stuff is focused on ActiveRecord.

Comment: For will_paginate, you can see answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551522/how-do-i-paginate-a-hash-of-arrays-using-the-kaminari-or-will-paginate-gem/20112337#20112337

Comment: For will_paginate, you can see answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551522/how-do-i-paginate-a-hash-of-arrays-using-the-kaminari-or-will-paginate-gem/20112337#20112337

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the Kaminari gem, you can add pagination to an array.

```
items = $redis.lrange("items-#{params[:id]}", 0, -1)
@items = Kaminari.paginate_array(items).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Then in your view it's as simple as

```
@items.each do |item|
   ...
end
paginate @items
```

Answer (score -1):

You will use will_paginate gem and a simple demo here http://gerardogc2378.blogspot.mx/2011/10/paginando-objetos-con-willpaginate.html